# Async accept with boost bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm attempting to bind `async_accept`'s handler to a **member** function.
The overload of `async_accept` I'm attempting to use is:

```
template<typename MoveAcceptHandler>
DEDUCED async_accept(MoveAcceptHandler && handler);
```

The `async_accept` handler requires the following signature:

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error,
   typename Protocol::socket peer);
```

I'm attempting to `bind` to the handler with the following:

```
_acceptor.async_accept( boost::bind( &http_server::accepted, this, ph::_1, ph::_2 ) );
```

My **member** handler function has the following signature:

```
void http_server::accepted( boost::system::error_code const& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket )
```

When I compile I'm receiving the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to object of type 'boost::_mfi::mf2 >'
>           unwrapper::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_], a[base_type::a3_]);

I'm unsure where my error is. I can of course just bypass the problem all together and just use a `lambda` but I'm curious as to what I have done wrong.

EDIT:

**http_server.hpp**

```
class http_server
{
public:
    http_server( std::string_view host, std::string_view port );
    void listen( );
private:
    void start_accept( );
    void handle_accept( boost::system::error_code const& ec );
private:
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> _ctx;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_context::work> _work;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
    std::vector<connection> _connections;
};
```

**http_server.cpp**

```
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

http_server::http_server( std::string_view host, std::string_view port):
 _ctx{ std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_context>( ) },
 _work{ std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_context::work>( *_ctx ) },
 _acceptor{ *_ctx },
 _socket{ *_ctx }
 {
     tcp::resolver resolver( *_ctx );
     tcp::endpoint endpoint =
        *resolver.resolve( host, port ).begin( );

     _acceptor.open( endpoint.protocol( ) );
     _acceptor.set_option( tcp::acceptor::reuse_address( true ) );
     _acceptor.bind( endpoint );
 }

void http_server::listen( )
 {
     uint32_t threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency( );
     while( threads > 0 )
     { 
         _thread_pool.create_thread( [ this ]( )
         {
             while( true )
             {
                 try
                 {
                     _ctx->run( ); 
                     break;
                 }
                 catch( std::exception const& ex )
                 {
                     std::cerr << ex.what( ) << '\n';
                 }
             }                 
         } );
         --threads;                            
     }
     _acceptor.listen( boost::asio::socket_base::max_connections );
     start_accept( );
 }

void http_server::start_accept( )
 {
     namespace ph = std::placeholders;

     std::cout << "Waiting for connection\n";
     _acceptor.async_accept( _socket, boost::bind( &http_server::handle_accept, this, ph::_1 ) );
}


void http_server::handle_accept( boost::system::error_code const& ec )
{
    if( !_acceptor.is_open( ) ) return;
    if( !ec )
    {
        connection& con = _connections.emplace_back( connection{ std::move( _socket ) } );
        std::cout << "Number of connections: " << _connections.size( ) << '\n';
        con.handle_requests( );
    }
    start_accept( );
}
```

Comment: sockets are move-only, so binding them into the handler by value is not a simple plan

Comment: @sehe Agreed, but as per `boost` docs, it is possible. Scroll to the bottom to see an example. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MoveAcceptHandler.html

Comment: I think you're getting that wrong. The fact that the handler will be moved when possible does *nothing* to make `bind` actually move the argument in at invocation. No bind does that (it would make the bind invalid after the first invocation).

Comment: So I used one of the other `async_accept` overloads which takes a socket as the first parameter and then requires a handler taking an `error_code` but I'm still getting this error.. Wish I could figure out what the issue is but this isn't a show stopper, like I said I can just use a lambda (which I've done) to skirt around the issue.

Comment: Maybe you can share some actual code, so we can see the problem

Comment: @sehe OK I posted some more code. Some of it wouldn't be relevant to the question at hand, so I can remove it if it's causing too much noise.

Comment: I also notice that if I pass a lvalue `error_code` instead of a placeholder, it compiles

Comment: Pro tip: make it a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) (aka [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)): https://wandbox.org/permlink/IjflS7umSuZgmygt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, the added context explained that `ph` was an alias for `std::paceholders`:

```
 namespace ph = std::placeholders;

 std::cout << "Waiting for connection\n";
 _acceptor.async_accept( _socket, boost::bind( &http_server::handle_accept, this, ph::_1 ) );
```

That doesn't work, unless you either use `std::bind` *or* you use the Boost Bind placeholders:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p1CP1PFuE2RPX2TC)</kbd>**

```
_acceptor.async_accept( _socket, boost::bind( &http_server::handle_accept, this, ::_1 ) );
_acceptor.async_accept( _socket, boost::bind( &http_server::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
_acceptor.async_accept( _socket, std::bind( &http_server::handle_accept, this, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
```

For some strange reason of bad luck Boost declares its placeholders in the global namespace (!!!). But Boost Lambda, Boost Phoenix, Boost Spirit and others do not. Never mix and match placeholders unless they were specifically designed for it.

Boost Asio's placeholders are compatible with both Boost Bind but not std::bind

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to correct the issue by changing this line:

```
_acceptor.async_accept( _socket, boost::bind( &http_server::handle_accept, this, ph::_1 ) );
```

To this:

```
_acceptor.async_accept( _socket, boost::bind( &http_server::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
```

So, instead of using either the `std::placeholders` or `boost::placeholders` I had to specifically use the `boost::asio::placeholders::error` in order for the function to `bind` correctly.